# Is it possible use RFCOMM in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm relatively new in iOS development.

I want to make a cross-platform Bluetooth app, in Android, I use RFCOMM to send **custom** data, like strings. When I googled 'iOS Bluetooth', I've found the `Core Bluetooth` framework in the results, it seems to be made for low-energy connections. I only want to use RFCOMM instead of other profiles because of two reasons:

1. I use RFCOMM to send **custom** data, like strings.
2. I want my app to be able to connect with non-apple devices.

Is it even possible to use RFCOMM in iOS? If not, are there any workarounds to connect with non-apple devices?

Comment: You can only use legacy profiles if your device is MFi certified. If it isn't then you need to use the BLE GATT profile. The use of GATT doesn't prevent you from sending strings or working with non-Apple devices.

Comment: How do I know if my device is MFi certified?

Comment: forget that. you can only accsss your devices. YOU need a MFi certification

Answer (score 6):

no, 'core bluetooth' on ios only supports BLE devices and only on a rather high level. there is only one specific profile being offered (GATT)

Now if you want RFCCOMM (part of SPP) you might be able to leverage the 'External Accessory' framework BUT you can only use only your app with a your device (as in: you manufactured it and now wrote an app to use it). You would also need a license from apple so ....... not really an option

Comment: @downvoter: please be atleast so fair as to leave a comment telling me what isnt correct

Comment: SEE: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html

Comment: Thats OS X. No drivers on iOS

Answer (score 1):

RFCOMM is part of the protocol stack and drives HSP and HFP. A simple SPP based application is also backed by RFCOMM. Your application should be okay with SPP implementation. The lower stack layer RFCOMM may not be directly exposed to third party app developers.

Comment: this says not YES and not NO and is not ios specific at all ;)

Comment: What I meant in my earlier comment is to try use SPP instead of RFCOMM directly. SPP sits one layer on top of RFCOMM. So, if Serial port profile is exposed (usually exposed on many platforms), you can implement what you need.

Comment: still true. the post explains what it is but fails to acknowledge the ios techs behind it. you cant just implement it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use BLE L2CAP you can check this iOS project https://github.com/github-deden/iOS_L2Cap

According to this screenshot taken from WWDC2019, L2CAP should be working for both BT classic and BLE and connect to to BR/EDR

[image]

Comment: That's BLE over L2CAP, not Bluetooth Classic.

Comment: Heard that BT classic is supported in iOS 13, but I don't have much details about what is the actual data you can transfer. Check this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901