# Two parallel iAP Bluetooth Connections

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

Is it possible to have two iAP Blueetooth connections open from a single iOS device (iPhone)? I know that you can be connected to more than one bluetooth device on the OS level. But will I be able to send/receive data on two parallel bluetooth connection (to two different devices) from my iPhone.
Can I talk to a device that only offers RFCOMM/SPP via the ExternalAccessory framework? These [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075775/is-it-possible-use-rfcomm-in-ios) do not seem to give a definitive answer to that question.

Comment: You can't communicate with SPP devices unless the device is MFi compliant and your app is associated with the MFi program member.

Comment: @Paulw11 I should have probably added that to the question but that part was already clear after my research. I am mostly interested in the question whether it is possible to have two iAP Blueetooth connections open from a single iOS device.